# How to do an Ajax call in beforeAll for Angular 2+ Protractor e2e tests?

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

I want to do a POST to my API in the `beforeAll` of Angular 6 e2e tests. I've tried various approaches, none seem to work. Here's a repro of my scenario.

Start with `ng new foobar` (Angular 6 CLI) and go into that folder. Open the `app.e2e-spec.ts` and add the following code inside the `describe` lambda:

```
let id: string;

beforeAll((done) => {
  fetch('https://example.org/my-api', { method: 'POST' })
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(r => {
      id = r;
      done();
    })
    .catch(err => done(err));
});
```

The reason I want to do the above is because I want to insert an test subject in the database via my API so that I can then use the ID that's returned in later e2e tests.

This unfortunately gives an error:

> Failed: fetch is not defined

I've tried some other options as well. First, I tried doing a native `xhr`, but then I get an error:

> Failed: XMLHttpRequest is not defined

Second, I tried doing `import { http } from 'https';` and then calling the `http.request(...)` function but that fails expectedly because VSCode already complained that

> [ts] Module '"https"' has no exported member 'http'.

Finally, I've also tried wrapping the `fetch` in a [`browser.executeAsyncScript(...)` call](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeAsyncScript) block, but then I seem unable to capture the result from my POST call outside the browser scope, to be used in the tests.

So, I'm at a loss. What is a good way to do an Ajax POST to my API in the `beforeAll` of an Angular 6 protractor end to end test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some good 'ole rubber duck debugging I found a solution:

```
beforeAll((done) => {
  const request = require('request');

  const options = {
    url: 'https://example.org/my-api',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', },
    json: true,
    body: { key: 'dummy value' },
  };

  const callback = (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode > 200 && response.statusCode < 300) {
      id = body;
      done();
    } else {
      done(error);
    }
  };

  request(options, callback);
});
```

The key takeaway is that this code is executed in a *Node.js* context, and that the way to get to a Node.js library for executing Ajax calls is `const request = require('request');` (or something similar with `http`).

The `done(...)` calls (and the fact that you require it as an argument in your lambda) make Jasmine and Protractor wait for the `callback` to happen.

Note that at first this approach didn't seem to work, but then I found that the `callback` was called but that my request was incorrect leading to a `400` status code. I recommend using [this VSCode e2e debugging setup](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Angular-CLI#debug-end-to-end-tests) to verify if things are working as expected if you still have troubles.